# How to locate window over all of apps (even if they are fullscreen-ed)

Tags: swift, macos, fullscreen, nswindow

So i did the following:

1. configured plist.info: `Application is agent(UIElement)` configured to "YES"
   (but possibly it is for iOS only ?)
2. 

```
wnd.collectionBehavior = [.stationary, .canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
wnd.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow)) + 2 )
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

both doing nothing!

All that can help is:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.prohibited)
```

but it is not solution for me as it's disable lot of other features and abilities of the app. =(

Is there exist some other ways to show window above fullscreen apps?

full code:

```
func openMainWnd(show: Bool = true) {
    if mainWndController == nil {
        let styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask = [ /*.closable,.miniaturizable, .resizable, .titled*/]
        
        let wnd = NSWindow()
        wnd.styleMask = styleMask
        wnd.title = "Main1"
        
        wnd.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: MainView(model: appVm) )
        wnd.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        wnd.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        wnd.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        wnd.isMovable = false
        wnd.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
        wnd.hasShadow = true
        wnd.titleVisibility = .hidden
        wnd.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        wnd.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        wnd.collectionBehavior = [.stationary, .canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
        wnd.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow)) + 2 )
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        
        wnd.setPosition(vertical: .top(offset: MainWndConfig.topOffset), horizontal: .center)
        
        mainWndController = NSWindowController(window: wnd)
    }
    
    if show {
        mainWndController?.showWindow(mainWndController?.window)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23503943/341994 ?

Comment: @matt looks like it is, but all of those solutions does not work. Also those question is related to objective-c, but not swift

Comment: But the answers there tell you quite clearly what you can and can't do. And asking the same question again won't change anything. (See Einstein's putative definition of lunacy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to use NSPanel instead of NSWindow + .nonactivatingPanel + few more things

call display of View in floating NSPanel from AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var mainWndController: NSWindowController?

    func openMainWnd(show: Bool = true) {
        if mainWndController == nil {
            let wnd = NSPanel(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200),
                                 styleMask: [.nonactivatingPanel],
                                 backing: .buffered,
                                 defer: true)
            
            wnd.orderFrontRegardless()
            
            wnd.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: MainView(model: appVm))
            wnd.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
            wnd.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
            wnd.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
            wnd.isMovable = false
            wnd.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
            wnd.hasShadow = true
            wnd.titleVisibility = .hidden
            wnd.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            wnd.backgroundColor = .clear

            wnd.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary] //[.stationary, .canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
            wnd.level = .mainMenu
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            
            
            wnd.setPosition(vertical: .top(offset: MainWndConfig.topOffset), horizontal: .center)
            
            mainWndController = NSWindowController(window: wnd )
        }
        
        if show {
            mainWndController?.showWindow(mainWndController?.window)
        }
    }
}


extension NSPanel {
    // Allow panel to become key, that is, accepts keyboard events
    // and give ability to use TextFields inside NSPanel
    open override var canBecomeKey: Bool { true }
}
```